# How to return List of nvarchar(150) from SQL function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I’m new to SQL so the question might be trivial. I have table Foo that has the following columns

```
ID -> nvarchar(150)
Name -> nvarchar(250)
```

I want to create function that return this

```
“Select ID from Foo”
```

Which will be list of nvarchar. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and what you mean by "list", because that is not a data type in SQL.

Comment: By "function" do you mean a stored procedure?